# Insertion sort in descending order (java)?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make an insertion sort program sort numbers in descending order. However, I'm not entirely sure what to do with this specific program.

```
    public static void insertionSort(int[] arr)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int curNumber = arr[i];
        int curIndex = i+1;
        while ( curIndex <= 0 && arr[curIndex] < curNumber)
        {
            arr[curIndex+1] = arr[curIndex];
            curIndex--;
        }
        arr[curIndex - 1] = curNumber;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

}
```

I've tried changing the < to a > on line 9 (while (curIndex <= 0 && arr[curIndex] < curNumber)), under the logic that the greater number will be moved, but it produces entirely wrong values for the sort. 
What should I do?

Comment: When I encounter problems like these, I often try to step through my code by doing all the operations on a piece of paper. It helps you understand your algorithm and the problem with it.

Comment: Why `while curIndex <= 0`? This is supposed to be checking for an out-of-bounds error, I think - it should be `>=`. Only `arr[curIndex] < curNumber` checks for *order*.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if currentIndex is >= 0, also the current index starts at i - 1

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] arr)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int curNumber = arr[i];
        int curIndex = i - 1;
        while ( curIndex >= 0 && arr[curIndex] < curNumber)
        {
            arr[curIndex+1] = arr[curIndex];
            curIndex--;
        }
        arr[curIndex + 1] = curNumber;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

}
```